# Would Voldemort have been recognisable to the average wizard?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Voldemort has quite a unique look and the wizarding world knew to fear him - much like Harry, everyone knew his name.

However, he worked quite stealthily almost until the end of the last book.

Obviously Dumbledore, Death Eaters, the Minister and Order of the Phoenix members would have known exactly what he looked like, but he hardly did publicity shoots. Add to this, his appearance changes quite frequently from handsome young man to snake-faced mystery man with his appearance presumably worsening with each new Horcrux created.

Would your average witch or wizard have recognised him should he come knocking?

Comment: Walt the Wizard: "Oh hei, it that Vol----"

Voldemort: "Avada Kedavra!"

Walt (now a ghost): "I guess it was..."

Comment: "Wait, are you Voldemort?" "Count the noses." "Oh ... oh yeah."

Comment: I wouldn't say his appearance changes _frequently_. It changed once, gradually over a long period of time.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet - But does it not get markedly worse each time he made a Horcrux? I would assume the change is not evenly spread out.

Comment: @ThruGog Presumably; but that's still only six or seven times over the course of quite a few years, hardly _frequent_. Would you say that Michael Jackson’s appearance changed frequently (not counting different looks and styles, just his transition from black human to white, noseless alien)? I'd call it a gradual change, even if it was probably based in several discrete changes.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet - Would I say Michael Jackson's appearance changed frequently? Yes! But I do take your point.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: ‘Mr Kreacher, _sir_, can I help you?’ ‘I doubt it.’ ‘Well, in that case, if you'll just excuse me...’ ‘No one can help me’ intoned Kreacher in his bullfrog's voice, and he bowed low, muttering to his knees about mudbloods in his mistress's old house. ‘Not that anyone's tried of course.’ ‘Is that so.’ ‘Hardly worth anyone's while to help a menial house-elf is it?’ ‘I'm sorry, sir, if...’ ‘Aren't you going to ask me what I want?’ The insect paused. ‘_What...do...you...want_?’ ‘I'm looking for someone.’ ‘Who?’ hissed the insect. ‘Voldemort,’ said Kracher, ‘he's over there.’

Comment: @leftaroundabout "The first Horcrux was the worst. The second Horcrux, that was the worst too. The third Horcrux, that was really bad. After that I went into a bit of a decline... But it's the Death Eaters that really get me down. The best conversation I had was over forty years ago, and that was with a Basilisk."

Comment: Knock knock. *“Who’s there?”* You know. *“You know who?”* That’s right - Avada Kedavra!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Initially, no

Tom Riddle was a promising student, but most people would not have met him. I don't recall any particular achievements of his that would have led to his face being featured in, for example, the Daily Prophet.

He took a low-key job at Borgin and Burkes, and was hardly ever in the spotlight.

> I know that several teachers, Professor Slughorn amongst them,
>   suggested that he join the Ministry of Magic, offered to set up
>   appointments, put him in touch with useful contacts. He refused all
>   offers. The next thing the staff knew, Voldemort was working at Borgin
>   and Burkes.”
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*

### Once he had become a "snake-faced mystery man," yes

Of course, most people had would not have seen Voldemort personally. But, as you mention, Dumbledore, the Order, and the Ministry (via Aurors) would all have seen him in combat. **I see no reason that they would not have disseminated information about his appearance throughout the magical community.**

Moreover, some of the Order members knew what he looked like. Surely they would have informed their family and friends? And we know how rumor spreads.... The same goes for Harry, but even more so.

In any case, people would *assume* that it was Voldemort if a snake-faced man showed up at their door. Snakes are heavily associated with Dark Magic, and certainly at this point everyone is aware that the premier Dark Wizard is Lord Voldemort. **So in that sense alone, they would recognize him, since they would instantly know it was he.**

We also have some evidence from the books:

Both Williamson and Fudge recognized Voldemort when he appeared in the Ministry:

> "He was there!" shouted a scarlet-robed man with a ponytail, who was
>   pointing at a pile of  golden rubble on the other side of the hall,
>   where Bellatrix had lain trapped only moments  before. "I saw him, Mr
>   Fudge, I swear it was You-Know-Who, he grabbed a woman and 
>   Disapparated!"
>
> "I know, Williamson, I know, I saw him too!" gibbered
>   Fudge, who was wearing pyjamas  under his pinstriped cloak and was
>   gasping as though he had just run miles.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

Of course, Williamson is an Auror and Fudge is his boss.

But even Grindelwald, who had been locked in a cell in his own prison for five decades, recognized Voldemort immediately:

> The emaciated figure stirred beneath its thin blanket and rolled over
>   toward him, eyes opening in a skull of a face. . . . The frail man sat
>   up, great sunken eyes fixed upon him, upon Voldemort, and then he
>   smiled. Most of his teeth were gone. . . .
>
> “So, you have come. I
>   thought you would . . . one day. But your journey was pointless. I
>   never had it.”
>
> “You lie!”
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*

And of course, as Sphoorthy Nutulapati mentioned, there was a woman in mainland Europe who also seemed to recognize him:

> “Gregorovitch?” said a high, cold voice.
>
> She shook her head: She was trying to close the door. A white hand
>   held it steady, prevented her shutting him out. . . .
>
> “I want Gregorovitch.”
>
> “Er wohnt hier nicht mehr!” she cried, shaking her head. “He no live
>   here! He no live here! I know him not!”
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*

Finally, Remus Lupin appeared to expect students to recognize Voldemort on sight (and to be more afraid of him than of giant spiders or banshees):

> "Well," said Lupin, frowning slightly, "I assumed that if the boggart
>   faced you, it would assume the shape of Lord Voldemort."
>
> Harry stared.
>   Not only was this the last answer he'd expected, but Lupin had said
>   Voldemort's name. The only person Harry had ever heard say the name
>   aloud (apart from himself) was Professor Dumbledore.
>
> "Clearly, I was
>   wrong," said Lupin, still frowning at Harry. "But I didn't think it a
>   good idea for Lord Voldemort to materialize in the staffroom. I
>   imagined that people would panic."

Comment: Well thought out. You're saying they would know it was him, but it's unlikely they'd have seen a photo or similar?

Comment: Exactly. Maybe there would have been a sketch, though. I doubt it, given how afraid people are to even say his name.

Comment: I *assume* it is to the Ministry's benefit (early on especially) to circulate his appearance. So little government pamphlets saying "The Dark Lord is a dangerous dark wizard who now looks like a human snake."

Comment: @ThruGog They probably wouldn't call him that, though—as Harry argues with Snape, only his followers ever called him The Dark Lord. ;-)  (I'm also wondering now if a Colin Creevey-type of character ever managed to get a snapshot of Voldemort after his changes…)

Comment: @Jonah - People might think I can't accept an answer, but you said yourself about Fudge and the Auror, I think Grindelwald knew who he was because he approached him at that time in his castle prison, not because he recognised him, and I'm not sure the woman definitely recognised him. He's scary looking and prevented her closing the door before she started screaming. (I have +1'd though).

Comment: @ThruGog Grindelwald immediately recognized Voldemort. How many Dark wizards worldwide do you think might want the wand? Or to break Grindelwald out, or to kill him? This isn't proof, but it is the strongest evidence we have.

Comment: @Jonah - Exactly: He knew who he was, but didn't necessarily recognise him by sight. I'm not saying you're wrong, I just don't think it quite puts the issue to bed.

Comment: I'm not saying there are photographs. I'm saying there are sketches and visual description.

Comment: @ThruGog I have even stronger evidence now.

Comment: @Jonah - You win! Five points and a shiny green tick to your Hogwarts house! I like it, I think that definitively answers the question.

Answer (score 6):

In Deathly Hallows, when Voldemort is searching for Grindelwald, he meets a woman (probably Central European from her accent) who opens the door for him. The instant she sees him, she starts freaking out. She keeps saying that she doesn't know who the person Voldy is searching for.

Two inferences. Either she knew Lord Voldemort and could recognize him by sight (Rumours, newspapers,propaganda by the Order etc.) or she was really freaked out by his nasal impairment.

Option one seems much more serious and keeping in tone with Rowling's style of writing at that point of time. Dark. Brooding.

So, yeah. It's highly probable that people knew Lord Voldemort, maybe not by sight but knew enough to recognize him.

Although, on Potterwatch, it's mentioned that numerous sightings of Voldy are reported. This kinda indicates that people are not a 100% sure about what You-Know-Who looks like.

**EDIT: Includes two references from the Seventh Book.**

In the chapter ***Magic is Might***, when the three of our protagonists are arguing about who gets to go the Ministry to steal the locket, Harry laughingly mentions Voldy's name which immediately causes his scar to hurt. Once he escapes to the bathroom, he has a vision of Voldy. I quote it below in bold. Notice the phrases in *italics*

**He was gliding along a twilit street. The buildings on either side of him had high, timbered gables; they looked like gingerbread houses.

He approached one of them, then saw the whiteness of his own long-fingered hand against the door. He knocked. He felt a mounting excitement. …

The door opened: A laughing woman stood there. *Her face fell as she looked into Harry’s face: humor gone, terror replacing it. …*

“Gregorovitch?” said a high, cold voice.

She shook her head: She was trying to close the door. A white hand held it steady, prevented her shutting him out. …

“I want Gregorovitch.”

“Er wohnt hier nicht mehr!” she cried, shaking her head. “He no live here! He no live here! I know him not!”

Abandoning the attempt to close the door, she began to back away down the dark hall, and Harry followed, gliding toward her, and his long-fingered hand had drawn his wand.

“Where is he?”

“Das weiß ich nicht! He move! I know not, I know not!”

He raised the wand. She screamed. Two young children came running into the hall. She tried to shield them with her arms. There was a flash of green light —**

This is a German speaking woman, apparently in an isolated village (gingerbread houses, plus Harry's constant glimpses and feelings of mountainous regions in his visions) who instantly gets scared looking at Voldy. She probably lives OUTSIDE England. She also behaves like his previous victims vis-á-vis Lily Potter, who kinda tries shutting the door against an armed wizard (I know, armed right? Sounds wrong. Wanded maybe). So, she probably might have known what to expect when a tall, pale British sounding guy with slits for nostrils comes knocking.

The following is an excerpt from the chapter ***The Deathly Hallows*** where Fred talks about Voldy's sightings on *Potterwatch*.

**“Yes, River, I can,” said Fred. “As our listeners will know, unless they’ve taken refuge at the bottom of a garden pond or somewhere similar, You-Know-Who’s strategy of remaining in the shadows is creating a nice little climate of panic. Mind you, if all the alleged sightings of him are genuine, we must have a good nineteen You-Know-Whos running around the place.”**

Again, we see the apparent confusion of people mistaking someone or something else for Voldy.

So, it is safe to say that **many** knew Voldy by sight. Not everyone though.

Comment: Could you find a quote? I wasn’t sure if this was a great question, but it would seem there is quite a lack of concrete evidence!

Comment: A quote for what @ThruGog?

Comment: Perhaps the character's precise reaction to seeing him as evidence that she did/didn't recognise him? Maybe we could infer more from that?

Comment: Please read my edited answer @ThruGog, might help shed some light.

Comment: You already had my +1 and I like your answer. I think all of the quotes in all of the answers are useful and add to a bigger picture.

Answer (score 4):

> Would your average witch or wizard have recognised him should he come
>   knocking?

**Maybe not**

People might have recognized Tom Riddle, mostly people who have studied along with him at Hogwarts. In addition, Tom Riddle was never known to be an extrovert outside of Hogwarts.

However, people might recognize Voldemort as the Dark Lord, from the stories or the tales; rather than actual portraits. So, people **might not** recognize the Dark Lord if he comes knocking.

And, a funny(maybe not) but important point to notice is that most of the conversations with Voldemort in the wizarding world, have ended up like this, as [Skooba's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125283/would-voldemort-have-been-recognisable-to-the-average-wizard#comment312221_125283) rightly puts:

> Walt the Wizard: "Oh hei, it that Vol----"  Voldemort: "Avada Kedavra!"
>   Walt (now a ghost): "I guess it was..."

Comment: Yes, a good argument from the other side. And sometimes I need reminding of this, but he was pretty stealthy most of the time.