# Is the noseless Voldemort joke a common joke inside the wizarding world?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

In *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*, one line in particular stood out to me:

> "I mean... you can't be Voldemort's son. You have a nose!"

In the first 7 Harry Potter books, although most wizards weren't brave enough to even say Voldemort's name, let alone openly mock him, it seems odd that people within the books would mock his noselessness as commonly as Harry Potter fans and readers would.

Would this have become as much of a common joke within the wizarding world as it is outside it?

Comment: Think of it this way... How often do we make fun of Hilter's appearance? Or even Kim Jung Un? Also, the play is non-sense...

Comment: Because JK Rowling has become Douglas Adams, substituting cheap laughs for a coherent plot?

Comment: @Randal'Thor to be fair, the Dirk Gently series had a coherent plot; and it was technically Jack thorne that wrote A Cursed Child.

Comment: @MikasaPinata OK; the only Adams I've read is HHGTTG (which I enjoyed, incidentally, even though it didn't have much of a plot). And yeah: Cursed Child is basically glorified fanfic, since it's not even written by JKR. Pardon my strong views :-)

Comment: In the books, Voldemort may or may not have been noseless, anyway. (Why doesn't my spellcheck like "noseless"? It seems a perfectly reasonable word. Much better than "spellcheck".)

Comment: @MattGutting yeah; "snake-like" nose never really gave an entirely noseless impression to me

Comment: @MikasaPinata - From *Goblet of Fire*: “…a nose that was flat as a snake’s with slits for nostrils.” It doesn’t seem like there’s much there.

Comment: [Obligatory reference](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/af/86/a1/af86a143ccd9b093bd0f8cd8e2e1f58d.jpg)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the accepted answer to the question that I asked, [Would Voldemort have been recognisable to the average wizard?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125283/would-voldemort-have-been-recognisable-to-the-average-wizard) It is agreed that most wizards knew what Voldemort looked like. They may not have seen a perfect image of him, but it has been agreed that Order members and Ministry people not trying to hide his reappearance would surely circulate his most defining features. The strange snakelike elements of his appearance would surely be the first thing to make others aware of.

This being the case, I am sure that many would make comments about his lack of nose. Add in the fact that many people (especially in Great Britain!) use humour to hide pain, tension and anxiety, I'd be willing to bet that at least some wizards would joke about Voldemort's appearance.

On a side note, I think the comment is primarily aimed at the audience of the show. The Internet is full to bursting with memes on Voldemort's nose, we like to see images of Ralph Fiennes in full makeup but with his nose still attached - I'm sure it's mostly aimed at that. Not the greatest thing to include in your special theatre show, but a little nod that I'm sure some people think is the height of great writing.